# Authenticated sharing in MASCOT protocol

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation

I am studying [MASCOT protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/505.pdf) for multiparty computation and I am stuck in the comprehension of the authentication protocol $\Pi_{[[ \cdot ]]}$ and its security proof.

Supposing the initialize phase of $\Pi_{[[ \cdot ]]}$ has been called, if one party $P_j$ wants to share some values $x_0, \dots, x_l$ using function **Input** of $\Pi_{[[ \cdot ]]}$, then at some point (step (3)):

for every $i \not= j$, $P_i$ and $P_j$ call $\mathcal{F}_{\text{COPEe}}.$**Extend**, where $P_j$ inputs $x_0, \dots, x_l$ (while in the initialize phase $P_i$ had input $\Delta^{(i)}$).
Thus $P_i$ receives $q_h^{(i,j)}$ and $P_j$ receives $t_h^{(j,i)}$ such that
$$q_h^{(i,j)} + t_h^{(j,i)} = x_h \cdot \Delta^{(i)}, \text{ for } h = 0, \dots, l.$$

Here $\mathcal{F}_{\text{COPEe}}$ is the correlated oblivious product evaluation functionality.

Then, for each $i \not= j$, $P_i$ sets $m_h^{(i)} = q_h^{(i,j)}$, while $P_j$ sets $m_h^{(j)} = x_h \cdot \Delta^{(j)} + \sum_{j \not = i} t_h^{(j,i)}$. In this way they obtain MAC shares of each $x_h\cdot\Delta$. Observe that here $j$ is a fixed value.

Instead, dealing with the security proof of $\Pi_{[[ \cdot ]]}$ (theorem 2 in the paper), it seems to me that $\mathcal{F}_{\text{COPEe}}$ is called in a different way and that MACs are computed differently too.

Indeed it seems that $\mathcal{F}_{\text{COPEe}}$ is called between each pair of parties $(P_i,P_j)$ for $i\not= j$, where $P_j$ inputs $x_h^{(j)}$, its share of $x_h$, for $h = 0, \dots, l$  (index $j$ is not fixed anymore). In this way, $P_i$ would receive $q_h^{(i,j)}$ and $P_j$ would receive $t_h^{(j,i)}$ such that:
$$q_h^{(i,j)} + t_h^{(j,i)} = x_h^{(j)} \cdot \Delta^{(i)}.$$
Then they seem to use as MAC shares the values:
$$m_h^{(i)} = x_h^{(i)}\cdot \Delta^{(i)} + \sum_{j \not = i} (q_h^{(i,j)} + t_h^{(i,j)}).$$

Can this make sense or am I misunderstanding something? I thought of this because it would make sense of some formulas used in the proof, where $j$ is not a fixed value. For example in (citing the paper, page 32):

"Generally, the sum of the honest parties' MACs is given by
$$\sum_{i \notin A} m^{(i)} = \sum_{i \notin A} x^{(i)}\cdot \Delta^{(i)} + \sum_{i \notin A} \sum_{j \not = i} (q^{(i,j)} + t^{(i,j)})".$$

Comment: Hi! Not entirely clear what the question is, could you rephrase it a bit?

Comment: I was wondering if (and possibly why) two different formulas seem to be used in the protocol $\Pi_{[[\cdot]]}$ and in its security proof, to compute the shares of MACs. In the protocol the MAC shares of $x_h$ are defined as $m_h^{(i)} = q_h^{(i,j)}$, for $i \not= j$ and $m_h^{(j)} = x_h \cdot \Delta^{(j)} + \sum_{j \not = i} t_h^{(j,i)}$ (where j is a fixed index). In the proof it seems to be used the formula $m_h^{(i)} = x_h^{(i)}\cdot \Delta^{(i)} + \sum_{j \not = i} (q_h^{(i,j)} + t_h^{(i,j)})$ for every $i$.

Comment: I'm thinking that, perhaps, the formula of the proof is different because the authentication protocol is used in this way:
To create a shared $[[x]]$, each party samples a share $x^{(i)}$, so $x = \sum_i x^{(i)}$ is not known to any party. Then, each party uses the protocol $\Pi_{[[\cdot]]}$ to create $[[x^{(i)}]]$. Next all parties obtain $[[x]]$ by computing (in shares) $\sum_i [[x^{(i)}]]$. In this way, the second formula written above, for MAC shares of $x$, is obtained.
If this is correct, however, I am wondering why this usage of the authentication protocol is considered in the proof.